# Creating summed summary rows in pandas dataframe with specific criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

Lets say I have the following pandas dataframe, and I am trying to post process the results to generate my (now blank) summary rows:

```
    code    entry_type  value1  value2  value3  value4
1   A       Holding     1.1     1.2     1.3     1.4
2   A       Holding     2.1     2.2     2.3     2.4
3   B       Holding     3.1     3.2     3.3     3.4
4   C       Holding     4.1     4.2     4.3     4.4
5   C       Holding     5.1     5.2     5.3     5.4
6   A       Summary     nan     nan     nan     nan
7   C       Summary     nan     nan     nan     nan
8   B       Summary     nan     nan     nan     nan
```

Essentially, I would like the value1-value4 in the summary lines to be the sum of the holdings in each of the code:

```
    code    entry_type  value1  value2  value3  value4
1   A       Holding     1.1     1.2     1.3     1.4
2   A       Holding     2.1     2.2     2.3     2.4
3   B       Holding     3.1     3.2     3.3     3.4
4   C       Holding     4.1     4.2     4.3     4.4
5   C       Holding     5.1     5.2     5.3     5.4
6   A       Summary     3.2     3.4     3.6     3.8
7   C       Summary     9.2     9.4     9.6     9.8
8   B       Summary     3.1     3.2     3.3     3.4
```

I have tried a few group-by lines of code, and came up with the following:

```
set = df[df['entry_type']=="Holding"].groupby('code')[['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4']].sum()
```

Which yields:

```
        value1  value2  value3  value4
code
    A   3.2     3.4     3.6     3.8
    B   3.1     3.2     3.3     3.4
    C   9.2     9.4     9.6     9.8
```

However I am not sure how I would apply this back to the original DataFrame, specifically due to the fact that the code order is not necessarily the same as the original DataFrame.  Any thoughts on how to apply this?  Or a better approach?  (Note- there is a bunch of additional data in the summary rows in other columns that already exists, so I can't just generate the new rows inline).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) can helps:

```
df1  = df[df['entry_type']=="Holding"]
         .groupby('code')[['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4']].sum()
#print (df1)

#if need filter `df` for only rows with Holding use boolean indexing
print (pd.concat([df[df['entry_type']=="Holding"].set_index('code'), df1])
         .fillna({'entry_type':'Summary'})
         .reset_index())

  code entry_type  value1  value2  value3  value4
0    A    Holding     1.1     1.2     1.3     1.4
1    A    Holding     2.1     2.2     2.3     2.4
2    B    Holding     3.1     3.2     3.3     3.4
3    C    Holding     4.1     4.2     4.3     4.4
4    C    Holding     5.1     5.2     5.3     5.4
5    A    Summary     3.2     3.4     3.6     3.8
6    B    Summary     3.1     3.2     3.3     3.4
7    C    Summary     9.2     9.4     9.6     9.8
```

Another possible solution with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) for replace `NaN` by `df1` with align by `index` values of `df`:

```
print (df.set_index('code')
         .combine_first(df1)
         .sort_values(['entry_type'])
         .reset_index())

  code entry_type  value1  value2  value3  value4
0    A    Holding     1.1     1.2     1.3     1.4
1    A    Holding     2.1     2.2     2.3     2.4
2    B    Holding     3.1     3.2     3.3     3.4
3    C    Holding     4.1     4.2     4.3     4.4
4    C    Holding     5.1     5.2     5.3     5.4
5    A    Summary     3.2     3.4     3.6     3.8
6    B    Summary     3.1     3.2     3.3     3.4
7    C    Summary     9.2     9.4     9.6     9.8
```